# Busboy Save Stream For Use Later

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, busboy

I'm trying to use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to allow clients to upload files to my Express web server.

I have the following middleware function I'm running for Express.

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    req.files = {};

    let busboy;
    try {
        busboy = new Busboy({
            headers: req.headers
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return next();
    }

    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        req.files[fieldname] = {
            file,
            filename,
            encoding,
            mimetype
        };

        // Need to call `file.resume` to consume the stream somehow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588458/894067)
        file.resume();
    });
    busboy.on("finish", next);

    req.pipe(busboy);
};
```

As you can see, I had to add `file.resume();` so that the "finish" event would be triggered, and call the `next` function for the middleware (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588458/894067).

The problem is, later on, when I want to consume the stream, it says `readable: false`. So I'm assuming the `file.resume();` discards the stream and doesn't allow it to be used in the future.

I basically want to get all the uploaded files and information associated with those files, store them on the `req.files` object, then consume the streams later, or not consume them if I don't want to use it. That way they remain streams and don't take up much memory, until I'm ready to consume the stream and actually do something with it (or choose to discard it).

What can I use in place of `file.resume();` to ensure that the "finish" event get triggers, while allowing me to use the stream later on in the lifecycle of the request (the actual `app.post` routes, instead of middleware)?

The client might also upload multiple files. So I need any solution to handle multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Would it make any sense to pipe the input stream into a PassThrough stream, like this?

```js
const Busboy = require('busboy')
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')

const multipart = (req, res, next) => {
  req.files = new Map()
  req.fields = new Map()

  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    const stream = new PassThrough()
    file.pipe(stream)
    req.files.set(fieldname, { stream, filename, encoding, mimetype })
  })

  busboy.on(
    'field',
    (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) => {
      req.fields.set(fieldname, { val, encoding, mimetype })
    }
  )

  busboy.on('error', (error) => {
    next(error)
  })

  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    next()
  })

  busboy.end(req.rawBody)
}
```

Comment: nice answer a few modifications, 1- busboy.end(req.rawBody) does not seem to work but this does req.pipe(busboy); 2- need to increase highWaterMark on PassThrough() if the files are large and you uploading more than one file in the same request otherwise it just freezes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle multiple files in a single request, the procedure is a bit tricky.

Busboy goes through a single stream and fires events whenever files arrive (in sequence). You cannot get separate streams for all files at the same time with Busboy. This is not a limitation from the library, this is how HTTP works.

Your best option would be to store all files in a temporary storage, and keep information for the next middlewares with `res.locals` :

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.files = {};
  // You need to ensure the directory exists
  res.locals.someTemporaryDirectory = '/some/temp/dir/with/randomString/in/it';

  let busboy;
  try {
    busboy = new Busboy({
      headers: req.headers
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    res.locals.files[fieldname + '_' + filename] = {
      filename,
      encoding,
      mimetype
    };
    // I skipped error handling for the sake of simplicity. Cleanup phase will be required as well 
    const tempFilePath = path.join(res.locals.someTemporaryDirectory, fieldname + '_' + filename);
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath));
  });

  busboy.on("finish", next);

  req.pipe(busboy);
};
```

The next middleware shall use `res.locals.someTemporaryDirectory` and `res.locals.files` to mind their businesses (that will require a clean-up phase).

This solution may seem sub-optimal, but HTTP is like it is. You may want to issue a separate HTTP request for each file instead, but I would not recommend it as you would encounter a bunch of other issues (such as synchronization of all requests + memory management).

Whatever the solution is, it requires to get your hands dirty.

Comment: I need to be able to handle multiple files. Also that doesn’t seem like a very good solution. It could create a race condition. Even if I’m expecting only one file, but the client uploads multiple, that next callback function will get called multiple times, and the file will be overridden multiple times. Overall doesn’t seem like a sound solution that solves the true problem.

Comment: Also even in my first sentence I say “files” as opposed to “file”. Therefore, this answer doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: Fair enough. This answer is indeed incorrect. I've investigated, and will write a correct answer shortly