# Why do I get undefined when trying to parse POST request with busboy? Using MEAN.IO stack

Tags: express, middleware, mean.io

I am trying to use busboy-connect to parse my request file that I send to the server. When I print out my request object, I get this huge Angular.identity object and when I try and parse the object using this code:

```
app.post("/compositions/fileUpload", function(req, res){
var fstream;

     req.pipe(req.busboy);

     req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 

        fstream = fs.createWriteStream('/files/' + filename);

        file.pipe(fstream);

        fstream.on('close', function () {

            res.redirect('back');

        });
    });
```

I error out on the "req.pipe(req.busboy)". I do require connect-busboy, and fs. I also make sure to tell my app to use busboy, so they should be there. However, I continue to get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:476:8)
    at Object.handle (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/packages/compositions/server/routes/compositions.js:38:10)
    at next_layer (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:213:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:12)
    at next (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:207:19)
    at next (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:38)
    at next (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:38)
    at next (/home/cyen/development/composelet/source/composelet/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:182:38)
POST /compositions/fileUpload 500 136.347 ms - -

_stream_readable.js:483
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:483:10)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

and I have no idea why. It seems there is another similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070511/node-busboy-express-4-ng-file-upload-doesnt-trigger-events) but it has not been solved yet. Would anyone know what this error could be caused by? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I did not require(connect-busboy) above my module in the global scope.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you explain more? What should I add in order for this example to work?

Comment: Well, my problem was that I didn't include connect-busboy. My error says that it cannot find the method 'on()' of undefined and that is because I didn't actually include the connect-busboy module. So, to fix this, at the top of my express file, I simply said: require('connect-busboy');